# Measurements for calculating the difference of the Outliers has on a Data Set

Tags: r, regression, probability, mathematical-statistics, dataset

Given a scenario where I compare a single column(independent variable) in a data set to the other columns(dependent variables). If I find the outliers from the independent variable. What could I test for by removing and keeping the outliers. What measurements could I take that could show the difference the outliers have for comparing the independent variable to the dependent variables? Although it is not a good thing to remove values from the raw data I want am curious to the approaches I could take with this.